# Creating a stopwatch that updates in UI thread Android

Tags: android, multithreading, textview, handler

I have been trying to figure out how to make a custom chronometer that is precise down to a hundredth of a second.  I have looked at a lot of the other similar questions and decided to try it using a thread and handler.

This is my custom handleMessage method:

```
public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    String timeText = msg.getData().getString("time");
    watch.setText(timeText);
}
```

The watch object is just a TextView that is initialized in onCreate().

And this is the main chunk of my run method:

```
while(true) {
    long timeElapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
    int hundreths = (int)((timeElapsed % 1000) / 10);
    int seconds = (int)((timeElapsed % 60000) / 1000);
    int minutes = (int)(timeElapsed / 60000);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("time", String.format("d:%02d.%02d", minutes, seconds, hundreths));
    Message msg = handler.obtainMessage();
    msg.setData(bundle);
    handler.handleMessage(msg);
}
```

I realize that the whole idea behind using a handler is that only the UI thread can update elements on the screen, but I am still getting a CalledFromWrongThreadException with the message that only the original thread that started created the View hierarchy can call methods on it.  I am confused as to what exactly I am doing wrong.

Comment: azertiti is right, you have to call `sendMessage()` instead of `handleMessage()`. If you want something to happen in your UI thread then the method has to be called from there - Handlers do that for you if you send the message to your UI thread Handler first. If you call it directly from your background thread then it gets executed in the background thread and everything executed  from there too and so on.

Comment: Okay, I understand my mistake now.  If I were to use the runOnUiThread method, would I call it from the Ui method that takes my runnable?  My concern is that it would then interfere with the Ui thread since the loop is continuous?

Comment: If you use runOnUiThread the runnable passed will be executed on another thread. There is no interference with the UI thread.

Comment: You can use `runOnUiThread` from everywhere, the code in `run()` inside the `Runnable` will always be executed on the UI thread. It just doesn't make sense to use it from the UI thread :) In your case you would use it in the loop instead of the Handler. And it's not really interfering with the ui thread since it uses a `Handler` itself. Instead of sending a `Message` the `Runnable` is sent. [see here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#post%28java.lang.Runnable%29)

Comment: So I have now tried both methods described here.  The runOnUiThread is slow to update the TextView, but the Thread + Handler methods works very well.  Thanks for everyones help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your error is because you are using handleMessage instead of sendMessage.

A simpler approach might be to use runOnUiThread method and give up the handler.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)